# nested loops - x86 NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Im trying to write assembly to print the ascii '*' in increasing order for 9 steps. :

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
```

I've written the loops based on how I would do things in c++. I based this code on the while loop. I think gets stuck on the less than and greater than comparison in 'print.' Am comparing my x and y variables incorrectly ( i.e should i be moving them to the registers in a different way)?
I've tried a lot of different tweaks but still no luck. I cant use anything beyond jumps.

```
;nasm 2.11.08

section .data


    x db '2' ; int x = 2
    y db '0' ; int y = 0
    star db '*'
    endl db 0xa

section .text
    global _start

_start:
begin:
    mov byte [x], '0'



    cmp byte [y], '9'

    jl print
    je end

print:

    mov ebx, [x]
    mov ecx, [y]   
    cmp ebx, ecx
    jl print2



    mov eax,4            
    mov ebx,1            
    mov ecx,endl       
    mov edx,1
    int 80h



    inc byte [y]

    jmp begin

print2:
    mov eax,4            
    mov ebx,1            
    mov ecx,star       
    mov edx,1
    int 80h 

    inc byte [x]

    mov ebx, [x]
    mov ecx, [y]

    cmp ecx, ebx
    jg begin
    jmp print 

end:
    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

Not sure where to go from here, would love some guidance.

Update:
So I figured it out thanks to some help from @PeterCordes

```
section .text

global _start

_start:


starts:

    mov     ecx, star   ;
    mov     edx, 1      ;;
    mov     ebx, 1      ;;; Print * 
    mov     eax, 4      ;;
    int     0x80        ;

    inc byte [x]        ; add 1 to x
    movzx cx, byte [y]  ; mov the 
    cmp byte [x], cl    ; check to see if x is less than y
    jle starts          ; x > y jump to top

    mov     ecx, endl   ;
    mov     edx, 1      ;;
    mov     ebx, 1      ;;; Print \n
    mov     eax, 4      ;;
    int     0x80        ;

    mov [x], byte '0'   ; reset x
    inc byte [y]        ; add 1 to y
    cmp byte [y], '9'   ; check to see if y is still less than 9
    jl starts           ; y > 9 jump to top


end:
    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80

section .data
    x db '0'            ; number of * per line 
    y db '0'            ; number of lines
    star db '*'
    endl db 0xa
```

Comment: the general idea of the loop is to for the inner loop to go the size of the outer value then inc the outer value.

Comment: You don't actually need a nested loop, just make `write` system calls with increasing length that start earlier and earlier in a `times 10 db '*'` / `db 0xa` buffer.  Or passing the same address to `write` every time, make the string longer by storing ```mov word [buf+edx], `*\n` ; inc edx``` or something.

Comment: re: your bug: `mov ebx, [x]` is a dword load that gets all 4 bytes from your data section: x, y, `*` and `0xa`.  Look at register values with a debugger.  A `movzx` load would work, but IDK why you'd want to use static storage in the first place when you still have some registers left to use for your counters.

Comment: @PeterCordes when i change to movzx, i get an infinite loop. unfortunately I don't have access to a debugger while I am doing this. This has to be done on an online code ground.

Comment: Developing asm (especially for a beginner) without using a debugger is a waste of your time (and the time of everyone that you're asking questions of).  https://www.onlinegdb.com/ has GAS assembly.  IDK if there's another online IDE with NASM.  If not, I'd suggest using `.intel_syntax noprefix` and porting your directives to GAS so you can debug your code.  Or install Linux in a VM, or other way of debugging locally before uploading your code to whatever online no-debugger piece of crap you need it on.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.